# ODL XML code! mininet switch flow not showing up

Tags: python, xml, mininet, opendaylight

I have written a python + XML code that pushes flow in to mininet switch (s2) through ODL controller. code is been executed perfectly as it responding **<Respone 200>**

[XML code response after running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7k3H.png)

but when I check the mininet switch it doesn't show the specific tables where as other tables flow (0 & 3) are showing, the highlighted once.

[flow display of mininet switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNnjk.png)

The purpose of this XML code is to check destination IPV4 address, than change the destination and source MAC address and than go to table 3.

```
odl_url = "http://10.1.1.129:8181/restconf/config/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node/openflow:2/table/2/flow/1"
print(odl_url)
headers = {'content-type': 'application/xml', 'accept': 'application/xml'}
dataXML="""<flow xmlns="urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory">
<id>1</id>
<instructions>
<instruction>
<order>0</order>
<apply-actions>
<action>
<order>0</order>
<set-field>
<ethernet-match>
<ethernet-destination>
<address>00:00:00:00:02:02</address>
</ethernet-destination>
<ethernet-source>
<address>00:00:00:00:02:10</address>
</ethernet-source>
</ethernet-match>
</set-field>
</action>
</apply-actions>
</instruction>
<instruction>
<order>1</order>
<go-to-table>
<table_id>3</table_id>
</go-to-table>
</instruction>
</instructions>
<match>
<ethernet-match>
<ethernet-type>
<type>2048</type>
</ethernet-type>
</ethernet-match>
<ipv4-destination>192.168.2.2/24</ipv4-destination>
</match>
<idle-timeout>0</idle-timeout>
<installHw>false</installHw>
<hard-timeout>0</hard-timeout>
<flow-name>PushFlow</flow-name>
<table_id>2</table_id>
<priority>5000</priority>
<strict>false</strict>
</flow>"""
add_flow_response = requests.put(odl_url, data=dataXML, headers=headers, auth=auth)
print(add_flow_response)
```

Can anyone please check my code and notify me the issue in the code because of which S2 is not displaying the table 2 flows.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the code but you have to make sure the switch supports the flow (e.g. tail OVS log at /var/log/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.log) as ODL will not return any REST failure for just writing a flow in the config DS.

Comment: I have posted another question regarding the error message. if you could help me out understand what the error is pointing out to, it will be a great help. new question link is; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124852/unable-to-understand-the-error-message-of-openvswitchd-log

Answer (score 0):

googling the ovs error messages you have in the other post made me wonder if
you are running mininet in openflow 1.0 or 1.3?

Comment: running the mininet using OpenFlow13 protocol

Comment: hmmm, not sure then. Maybe start trimming down the flow xml you have to something bare minimum and see if that works, then add elements back slowly to see if there is something specific that is causing the trouble.

Comment: Hi Jamo, thanks I did the trimming down and was able to found out the issue,"the ethernet source code in the set field was causing the issue when it was in order 0 of the action field. I created another action field with order 1 and put the ethernet source there and table 2 flow apeared". I would seem the in action field only 1 action can be taken per order